# Is it possible to fill a pdf-form only with javascript?

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-form

I have a existing PDF with a form in it (you can select the fields and write in it on acrobat reader). I won't change the pdf. Only fill the form. Because i have many datas (like other names, other usernumbers) i want to fill the form automatically. Is it possible to do this, only with javascript and save the pdf. I just want to fill the form.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Are you looking for free (unpaid) solution only? By javascript, you mean client side only? Or is nodejs ok? If client side only, why?

Comment: if it's possible a unpaid solution. I haven't access in my company for a web server and i can't use php. beacuse of that, i want to use it only with js and html

Comment: and i can't use jQuery ajax or something. it is blocked

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with [PDFTron SDK](https://www.pdftron.com/) (company I work for). Note, this is a commercial SDK.

This is a completely client side only solution, see [supported browsers here](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/client-only-deployment#browser-support).

Here is [sample showing form fields](https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/demo/pdf-forms/) in action with the viewer. Note, you don't have to use the viewer, you can just use the SDK.

This guide shows the API's for iterating/finding/editing form field values.

https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/form-apis

Comment: i get this message:Uncaught (in promise) Viewer is on a different domain, the promise from WebViewer function is rejected and API functions will not work because of cross domain permissions. See https://pdftron.com/kb_cross_origin for more information.

Comment: And it is a paid tool. I want something for free

Comment: Regarding the different domain, then you want to see this guide on running across two domains. https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/wv-inside/#loading-webviewer-from-another-domain Though for evaluation purposes I am not sure why you are doing this, since hosting WebViewer lib on same domain as the website is the most common deployment anyway. As for the paid/free you indicated you preferred unpaid, but it appeared you were open to a paid solution. If you require an unpaid solution, then perhaps you should update your question to make that requirement clearer.